# Wi-fi adapter not recognized on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, drivers

I bought a wireless adapter Realtek 8812BU Wireless. It came with a small CD for the driver but since I don't have a CD-ROM I looked for the driver on the Internet.

After a few searches, I managed to install the right one on my Windows 11 machine, it appears as WI-FI 3 on Windows. So everything works as expected so far.

[image]

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to install a driver for my Kali Linux Virtual machine. The adapter is getting recognized by the VM but when I run ifconfig it doesn't appear so I asume I dont have a good driver.

[image]

[image]

Sorry if my problem seems trivial, I'm new to networking and also to linux.

Comment: If, as you say, "I'm new to networking and also to linux", then Kali is not for you. Learn about Linux, networking, security tools, etc with a friendlier Linux distribution.

Comment: That's true, as Kali explains themselves: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#:~:text=The%20fact%20of%20the%20matter,general%2Dpurpose%20Linux%20desktop%20distribution please simply use a different Linux distribution for now!

Comment: I have started an ethical hacking tutorial on Udemy, that's why I'm using it over others. After I finish this tutorial I will definitely start another tutorial on Linux, currently, I have very little experience with it, only from college. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I managed to find a good git repo for the driver:

https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver

The installation instructions are in the ReadMe file.